# find the difference between two date values in Sybase database which one of date is null

Tags: java, sql, database, sybase

I use a query which i want to check if difrence in hourers is more then ziro.
In my datebase sometimes i have null value for one of two dates or date is emptey.

my question is what should i expected if one of date is null or has no value?

**Query:**

```
 SELECT * FROM cars_db..lux 
 WHERE dos_nr < 10000 
 AND DATEDIFF(hh, in_time, out_time ) > 0
```

Comment: use `coalesce` to substitute the `null` date with a desired value and get the difference.

Comment: You will get `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`.

Comment: It should only take a couple minutes for you to run a few tests to see how DATEDIFF() handles NULL inputs.  I think what you really need to answer is: 1) What do you mean by `date is emptey` - is it NULL, is it a single space, is 1/1/1900, is it something else? 2) How do you want your query logic to handle a NULL/empty value - generate an error, ignore, treat as if difference in hours > 0, treat as if difference in hours < 0, something else?

Comment: If either argument is `null` the result will be `null`, too. If you use the result in the `WHERE` clause, then the condition would fail, thus  filtering out the row.

Comment: Does it means that row will not be retrieved?